# how to use TimeZone.getAvailableIDs to check input timezone is valid or not in my code

Tags: scala

This is my code, it will convert a string type of timestamp to unix timestamp, and I want to check if the input timezone is valid or not. Seems I can't put an if in it, how can I do that?

```
def parse_string_type_time(params: List[JValue]): JValue = params match {
  case a :: b :: c :: Nil =>
    val res = for {
      JString(timestamp) <- parse.toString(a)
      JString(pattern) <- parse.toString(b)
      JString(timezone) <- parse.toString(c)

      df = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern)

      _ = df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timezone)) // instead of using getTimeZone(), I want to use TimeZone.getAvailableIDs.

      jd <- Try(JString(df.parse(timestamp).getTime.toString)).toOption
    } yield jd
    res.getOrElse(JNothing)
  case _ => JNothing
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st - You *can* do an `if` test inside a `for` comprehension. It's called a "guard" and the syntax is a little different.

```
for {
  x <- aList
  if x > 5
  ...
}
```

I can also be done like this.

```
for {
  x <- aList if x > 5
  ...
}
```

2nd - How are you going to test if `timezone` is valid? `getTimeZone()` simply defaults to GMT on bad input.

---

Your plan should work...

```
  . . .
  JString(timezone) <- parse.toString(c)
  if getAvailableIDs().contains(timezone)
  . . .
```

Note that there is no "then" block or `else` clause. The guard simply determines if the `for` code continues or terminates.

Comment: hi jwvh, for test if timezone is valid, I think I can use TimeZone.getAvailableIDs first, to check if the timezone is good, and then call df.setTimeZone, is that correct?